# angularjs directive different binding from array

Tags: angularjs, binding, scope, compilation, directive

While `angular.forEach` it returns only last value from `personList`. 
How for each object in personList show info with created `directive`?

> I need exactly solution in forEach loop.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $compile) {
        var personList = [
            { name: "John", age: "20" }, 
            { name: "Peter", age: "25" } 
        ];

        angular.forEach(personList, function(p, i) {
            $scope.person = { name: personList[i].name, age: personList[i].age };
            var personInfo = ($compile)('<person-info></person-info>')($scope);
            var body = document.querySelector("body")
            var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");


            body.append(parentDiv);
            parentDiv.append(personInfo[0]);
        });
    });

app.directive("personInfo", function () {
    return { template: '{{ person.name }} is {{person.age}} years old' }
});
```

In Html:

```
Peter is 25 years old
Peter is 25 years old
```

Comment: ok thats totally wrong you should avoid to do that kind of manipulation, first you should not add element of a directive the way is to add stuff to a model not directly to DOM ,second this should not happen in controller(link is where you compile stuff )

Comment: Why would you want to do this in your controller instead of using `ng-repeat` with your directive in the markup?

Comment: @Lex i need to do it dynamically

Comment: The view will update dynamically on a change to the `personList`. This is a pretty basic part of the Angular framework and as pointed out you should not be doing DOM manipulation in a controller.

Comment: any element you create manually will never be handled by Angular itself. so yes, it's definitely not a way you should go here.